# Staging environment does not take the correct connection string Asp.Net Core

Tags: environment-variables, asp.net-core-mvc, appsettings

Staging environment does not take the correct connection string.

I have three environments. Development, Staging & Release. 
My appsettings looks like that:

```
{
 "Data": {
  "DefaultConnection": {
  "ConnectionString": "My connection string"
}
},
 "Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": false,
  "LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Verbose",
  "System": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Information"
  }
 }
}
```

I have two more files with the name appsettings.Staging.json & appsettings.Release.json.
Under project properties I made two profiles: Staging & Release witch both have a Hosting: Environment with the Value Staging in staging and Release in Release. It works fine in VS but when I am uploading it to Azure it always takes the default appsettings with my localhost connection string instead of my online DB.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't store you connection string if it has sensitive data in the text file and should set the value directly AppSettings in Azure for production (or look at something like [Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/))  to set the value. I would recommend reading https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/app-secrets.html and https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html.

To address the problem of reading the values from the correct setting file see below.

You need to set the environment value in Azure.  In the Azure portal, on your WebApp go to `All Settings->Application Settings->AppSettings` and add the setting `ASPNET_ENV` or `Hosting:Environment` with the value of `Staging` (or any other environment you are interested in.

For reading the `appsettings.Staging.json` file you would do something like:
[image: set staging environment]